# Intercept (bluetooth) audio to add preamble sound

Tags: bluetooth, audio

Is it possible to intercept the audio going to bluetooth?

When using a bluetooth headset for either navigation or exercise (endomondo), if the bluetooth is not getting any audio, it hibernates, taking a second or two to wake up.

So the prompt I hear could be "meters turn left" (with the value missing), because the first part is cut off.

It is not any audio files which could be edited; it is synthesized speech, and the problem exists for many apps.

So is it possible to make a "driver" which intercepts the audio, and sends a "Gong" chime or something to wake up the bluetooth before sending the speech audio?

I could probably make a low volume or sub/supersonic audio file to play to "keep the channel open" if I don't want to listen to music, but I'm afraid it will drain the battery.

Comment: Interesting scenario, though I'd just change my headphones if this happens to me... Just saying.